# Rails Ajax: .js.erb rendered as text, not JS

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm having a trouble with rails3 to render Javascript (If this is relevant, I use JQuery and it works fine since it's used in numerous other parts of the application) instead of html.

What I have:
I a view, I have this link:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_repreneur_path(@user_repreneur, :format => :js), :remote => true %>
```

First of all, I don't really get why I have to add :format => :js to get the controller to use the JS view, and not the HTML one.
Here is the code of the controller:

```
def edit
    @user_repreneur = UserRepreneur.find_by_id_view(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
    end 
end
```

At the beginning of the controller class, I have this line:

```
  respond_to :js, :html
```

My edit.js.erb file contains a single line with an alert.
However, when rendering the page, the JS is rendered as text, and therefore is not executed.
I tried to change the format.js line to

```
format.js { render :layout => false }
```

But it doesn't change anything.
I guess I am missing something, but I really don't see what...

Thanks a lot in advance, cheers!

PS: I don't know if this is helpful, but before I add the  :format => :js bit in my link helper, the view was always rendered as HTML, and if I commented the format.html line, I had a 406 Not Acceptable error on the server side.

Comment: Is it really send by an ajax request? you can check in the console or in firebug console

Comment: having respond_to :js, :html at the beginning of the controller means you are anticipating using respond_with in your actions (as opposed to respond_to).  i wonder if this redundancy could be causing issues - have you tried erasing that first line in the controller?  also you should not need to add :format => :js to the view

Comment: In the chrome console, when I click on the link I see a GET request, with a 304 response code and a text/javascript type.
Also, commenting the line in the controller doesn't change anything, but thanks for the info :)!
I know I shouldn't need to specify the format in the view, but otherwise it always renders HTML... strange.

Comment: It was loaded, but before jquery.js, thus not working properly. Thank you very much!

Comment: hi? where can I find the place where rails.js is loaded? and where would be the correct place to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think the problem is with your server-side code. It all looks good to me. And the fact that it is rendering `edit.js.erb` proves that your server-side code is working fine.

The problem is on your client-side. When it receives the Ajax response, it isn't executing it as javascript. It is executing it as text.

I have recently had this problem myself and I wish I had my code with me but I'm at work. However, I personally wrote the jQuery Ajax request instead of relying on `:remote => true` since that option is mostly used in forms.

Try giving your `link_to` an id and then put this jQuery in your `application.js` or wherever.

```
$('#link_id').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
      type : 'GET',
      url : '/:controller/:action/',
      dataType : 'script'
   });
   return false;
});
```

This will grab the link's click event, send a request to the server which should return your `edit.js.erb` file, and then execute it as script.

Mind you, there is a lot of security concerns to take into account as well as authenticity tokens and the like. However, this should get your alert to execute and get you on the right path to completing your app.

Read up on [jQuery's Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for further options and details about POSTing data as well.

Hope this helps.

UPDATE: Other possible solutions include using UJS as a Javascript driver. You can read the documentation at https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs and view a Railscast on the topic [Unobtrusive Javascript](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript) using UJS.

Comment: This works, thank you very much.
However, I don't really understand why I have to use such a trick...
and why :remote => true doesn't appear to be working properly on links.

Comment: I have been pondering that a lot myself. Like I said, I'm much more into hand-coding all my Javascript but I have found a few more resources that are sure to help you and have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: You should take a look at the problem raised by tommasop, in the comments to my questions. It seems a silly thing to check, but it solved my problem.

Comment: lol Amazing how such a little thing can cause such a cascading effect of frustration.

Answer (score 1):

Seems a little late to be providing this answer, but better late that never.

You are mixing up respond_to and respond_with.  At the top of your controller class use respond_to :js, :html.  Then put this in your edit action

```
def edit
  @user_repreneur = UserRepreneur.find_by_id_view(params[:id])
  respond_with @user _repreneur
end
```

Answer (score 1):

js.erb files render as text if you don't have the jquery_ujs lib included in your application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

And you'll need the following gems in your gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on rails,

Simple fix: Add data-type="script" to the form.
Source: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/Unobtrusive-scripting-support-for-jQuery