# js.erb is rendered as text

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a link that needs to show a hidden Div on click.
For it, I am using :
 `<%=link_to video.title,display_path(:format=>:js,:id=>video.id),:remote=>true%>`
in the controller i have:

```
def display
        @video=Video.find(params[:id])
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js 
        end
    end
```

and in the js.erb, i have,

```
$('#vid_<%=@video.id%>').fadeIn('slow');
```

But when i run the app, upon clicking the link, the js.erb is rendered as text.It just displays:

```
$('#vid_<%=@video.id%>').fadeIn('slow');
```

Comment: What version of Rails you using? and what JS libs are your using ?

Comment: macarthy, iam using Rails 3.0.6 and jQuery library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution.I made a silly mistake.I forgot to skip prototype while creating the App.This caused trouble when i tried to use Jquery.Its all good now.

Answer (score 0):

You should read

[Rails Ajax: .js.erb rendered as text, not JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311247/rails-ajax-js-erb-rendered-as-text-not-js)

for a full explaination

Comment: i have read that.But i had implemented this same code earlier and it worked just fine.Wonder why its not working

Comment: macarthy, i read that.There its mentioned that another solution is to use rails jQuery adapter and thats exactly what i'm doing.Firebug even raises errors if i purposely make typo in rails.js

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything right, but you can improve your code a little

**views**

```
# use spaces to ident all this stuff and write less if it is possible:
<%= link_to video.title, [:display, video], :remote => true %>
```

**controller**

```
class VideosController < ApplicationController  
  respond_to :html, :js
  ...
  def display
    @video=Video.find(params[:id])
    respond_with @video
  end
  ...
end
```

**display.js.erb**

```
$('#vid_<%= @video.id %>').fadeIn('slow');
```

Be sure, that you have installed jQuery:

```
rails g jquery:install
```

and included it into your application layout file.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```