# Rails 3.1 live preview

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript, markitup

I would like to have a live preview similar to the one here on stackoverflow.
Using Rails 3.1 and RedCloth, I can not seem to understand how to make it work.

I tried making my own Ajax call such as this (inside my posts.js.coffee)

```
$ ->
 $('#post_content').keyup ->
  $.post('posts/preview', $('#post_content').val(), null, "script")
```

and having a function inside the controller

```
def preview
 @content = params[:post_content]

 respond_to do |f|
  f.js
 end
end
```

in preview.js.erb I put

```
$("#preview").html("<% raw RedCloth.new(@content).to_html %>");
```

I added the resource

```
resources :post do
 post 'preview', :on => :collection
end
```

but it doesn't work.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Ajax is going to have too much latency for a live preview like Stack Overflow's. What you want is a JavaScript markdown library. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134235/is-there-any-good-markdown-javascript-library-or-control (Note that you can also run that same markdown library on the server using ExecJS, which of course comes bundled with Rails 3.1.)

Comment: I believe this question is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311247/rails-ajax-js-erb-rendered-as-text-not-js

Comment: In the future, Guy, it would be wise to include some debugging information. *Why* doesn't it work or what *does* it do that is unexpected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your words of wisdom,
eventually I did what you guys said, as it was far wiser to parse the preview on the client-side.
I switched to Markdown parser (server-side) [bluecloth 2.1.0](http://deveiate.org/projects/BlueCloth) and

```
gem "bluecloth", "~> 2.1.0"
```

and as for the client-side parser I used [PageDown](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown)

then I only needed to add a little snippet to make it work.

```
converter = new Markdown.Converter()
$ ->
  if $('#post_content').val() isnt ''
   $('.preview').empty().append(converter.makeHtml($('#post_content').val()))
$ ->
  $('#post_content').keyup ->
    $('.preview').empty().append(converter.makeHtml($('#post_content').val()))
```

notice it is not sanitized!

Comment: hey Guy.. I am trying to do the same as you. I found that using this parser is great! EXCEPT, when I write converter.makeHtml(string) into a file eg main_file.js it causes other scripts that are run later to not work. Did you find this ever?

Answer (score 0):

You've specified `"script"` as the data type, which *should* make the response run as JavaScript. Check whether the response is correct by writing:

```
$.post('posts/preview', $('#post_content').val(), ((js) -> console.log js), "script")
```

There are some important caveats with the `"script"` data type approach. As the [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) docs say, "This will turn POSTs into GETs for remote-domain requests." I'm assuming this is a same-domain request, but that's worth keeping in mind.