# Rails pass params dynamic by using link_to

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am stuck, maybe it's just a silly question. There's a sort button, I need to use it to sort my question list.

What I do is that, I create a `link_to` like

```
<%= link_to xx_path(:is_sort => true, :remote=> true , :method=> :post %>
```

Then the controller will do sorting, `respond_to sort_question.js.erb` and render a sort question list.

But when I click the sort button again, I need to render the original question list.

So maybe `:is_sort => true` became `:is_sort => false` dynamically.

I've tried to use `Jquery` ajax, but it will return `text` instead of `script`. Furthermore, according to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311247/rails-ajax-js-erb-rendered-as-text-not-js), this way may cause security issue.

BTW, I don't want to sort in `front-end` because this question list do a lot of actions like create, delete or edit.

Comment: So you want the Sort link to sort the results and if the user is viewing the sorted results and they click the link the results go back to unsorted. Is that right?

Comment: Yes! That is what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

When sort has not been clicked `is_sort` will be set to `true` and when it has been clicked `is_sort` will be set to `false`.

```
xx_path(:is_sort => !params[:is_sort])
```

Comment: @CodaChang did you take a look at this answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```
<%= link_to xx_path(:is_sort => true), :remote => true %>
```

Comment: Ah, it seems not solve any problem. The server will get true instead of dynamical boolean value.

Comment: so What params it will pass?

Comment: I want to achieve that first time send `true`, second time send `false`, third send `true` again and so on.

Comment: <%= link_to xx_path(:is_sort => params[:is_sort] == true ? false : true), :remote => true %>